Pyrogram не оставляет комментарий, что делать?
У меня есть pyrogram скрипт который оставляет комментарии под постами. Если я с одного аккаунта создаю канал, и с другого аккаунта публикую комментарий(скриптом) то все работает. Если я вступаю в чужой канал и приходит новый пост, то скрипт его просто даже не видит, будто я не состою в канале. В чем может быть проблема?
P.S channel = основной канал; channel_chat = канал с комментариями
async def handle_message(client: Client, message: Message, channel, channel_chat):
if message.chat.id == channel_chat:
    return
content = message.text or message.caption
comment_prompt = f"Пожалуйста, оставьте комментарий по теме следующего поста (комментарий из 1 предложения, 5-15 слов): {content}"
comment = chat_with_openai(comment_prompt, config.api_key)

try:
    last_message = await client.get_discussion_message(channel, message.id)
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await last_message.reply(comment)
    print("+")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Ошибка при ответе на сообщение: {e}")

@app.on_message(filters.chat(config.channel1))
async def main(client: Client, message: Message):
await handle_message(client, message, config.channel1, config.channel_chat1)

Я столкнулся абсолютно с такой же проблемой, Егор. Ищу решение. Но я чувствую, что телеграм что-то обновил и теперь не работает это вообще. Мы не единственные с такой проблемой. Если ты найдешь решение, пожалуйста, напиши об этом

проблема решена. Нужно удалить pyrogram(pip uninstall pyrogram) и установить fork от pyrogram(pip install pyrotgfork). Импортировать эту библиотеку не нужно, импортируется так же pyrogram. Все что нужно - удалить pyrogram и установить pyrotgfork.

проблема решена. Нужно удалить pyrogram(pip uninstall pyrogram) и установить fork от pyrogram(pip install pyrotgfork). Импортировать эту библиотеку не нужно, импортируется так же pyrogram. Все что нужно - удалить pyrogram и установить pyrotgfork.
